# CodeIgniter: removing 'index.php' from URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, tankauth

I have answered this question previously and even posted the answer to it by myself. I tried most of the answered questions, but it still didn't work. The first question is regarding placement of the `.htaccess` file, should I keep it with application folder or inside it? and the next question is 'How should I remove the `index.php` from URL'?

.htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Config.php code:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

and if possible do also suggest a detailed tutorial regarding how to customize TankAuth or any other authentication library which can be easier. I am using Windows 8.1 and Wamp Server.

Any suggestion or help is appreciated.

Comment: which operating system you are using.If you are using ubuntu then you have to enable the mod rewrite.

Comment: @sonamgupta Windows 8.1

Comment: so try my .htaccess code once

Comment: I added htaccess I use and also links for more htaccess

Comment: See : http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html      and for instance: http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess.shtml    If the standard solutions are not working, verify mod_rewrite is enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

place ./ before your index.php rewrite rule.

or this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

For more detail refer link:https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html

Comment: In which folders htaccess file you placed that code

Comment: Do you refer that link which I have given

Answer (score 1):

it works on me, I use v2.2.6 by the way

- Create .htacccess on the same dir as your index.php
- Modify index_page and base_url value in /application/config/config.php

here is what it looks like

[picture image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3Qi5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this htaccess works fine windows 7 and 8.1 and xampp

Make sure you place the .htaccess in **main directory** and not the application folder.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Config

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

More htaccess https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

application > config > config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

definitely it will work.

Answer (score 0):

i think it will help you,

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

in config.php

```
    $http = 'http'.((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 's' : '').'://';
    $newurl = str_replace('index.php', '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
    $config['base_url'] = "$http".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].''.$newurl;
    $config['modules_locations'] = array('http://localhost/astrido_admin/application/' . 'modules/');

$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in `config.php` change this

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

and in **.htaccess**(NOTE: this should be place outside application folder)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

> **Note:** There are lot of **duplicate question**. So before Ask New Question please check your dropdown menu(its comes with when you start typing title of your question) whether its exist or answer provided.

Comment: and 'THE DOWN VOTER'I have tried all the options available in the dropdown and posted the question after they didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

1.config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';     change  to     $config['index_page'] = '’;
```

2.Create .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```