# mod_rewrite CodeIgniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

Now URL for my website is for example: http://localhost/xxx/index.php/welcome/

I want to change this to: http://localhost/xxx/welcome/

My .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

My config.php file:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/xxx/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

But my new URL still doesn't work. What should I add there?

Comment: This question may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30933255/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url removing index.php has been ask hundreds of times on stack over flow. Don't touch the htaccess in application folder.

Comment: Does anything actually work? Why are you denying access to the site? `Require all denied`

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following mod_rewrite. It actually works and I saw this on one of the tutorials I watched [here](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Mod-rewrite) and here is the .htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foldername/foldernameifapplicable/foldernameifapplicable

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: ooops. sorry for that. i will edit it right, btw thanks for the reminder,

Answer (score 0):

I do not recall all the changes made, but I followed the following tutorial and it did what you ask.

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I752ofYu7ag
```

htaccess looked like this

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```